# How to get CSS content attribute as string in javascript

Tags: javascript, css

Say I have the following CSS:

```
content : "\F069";
```

I tried

```
window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("id"), ":after").getPropertyValue("content").toString();
```

It gave me the symbol """"

How can I get the string "\F069" as a result instead?

Comment: You won't be able to get the exact string that was used like that, but can work it out using `''.codePointAt(0).toString(16)`

Comment: Thanks @cmbuckley It works

Answer (score -6):

You should do something like :

```
window.getComputedStyle(
    document.querySelector('#id'), ':after' 
).getPropertyValue('content');
```

Example here : http://jsfiddle.net/karlgroves/uqcUu/ or here http://jsfiddle.net/Ts6jh/2/

Comment: neither of those JSFiddle examples produces the result "\F069" as requested in the question. Perhaps you didn't read the question properly before answering?